# Google fonts don't show on my chart, only my system default

Tags: r, fonts

I am using RStudio on Debian 9.3. I want to use the library `showtext`. I ran this code:

```
library(showtext)
font_add_google("Lobster", "lobster")

showtext_auto()

plot(1, pch = 16, cex = 3)
text(1, 1.1, "A fancy dot", family = "lobster", col = "steelblue", cex = 3)
```

The resulting chart is supposed to look like this...

[image]

But on my computer, it looks like this...

[image]

Comment: Don't you have any warnings when running the `plot(); text()` commands?

Comment: @storaged No warnings, nor any other message is posted to console.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with RStudio's graphics device. It does not happen with `x11()` or `pdf()`.

Comment: @RalfStubner What would I need to do? I'm unsure what code I m must run

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some incompatibility between the `sysfonts` package used by `showtext` and RStudio's graphics device. At least I can reproduce the issue in RStudio, but not when using a different graphics device:

```
library(showtext)
font_add_google("Lobster", "lobster")

showtext_auto()

plot(1, pch = 16, cex = 3)
# text in some sans-serif font
text(1, 1.1, "A fancy dot", family = "lobster", col = "steelblue", cex = 3)

x11()
plot(1, pch = 16, cex = 3)
text(1, 1.1, "A fancy dot", family = "lobster", col = "steelblue", cex = 3)
# run this line after looking at the graph
dev.off()

pdf(file = "test1.pdf")
plot(1, pch = 16, cex = 3)
text(1, 1.1, "A fancy dot", family = "lobster", col = "steelblue", cex = 3)
dev.off()
browseURL("test1.pdf")
```